# 詰まらないとは詰まるから作りました？

Tags: etymology

I assume 詰まらない came from 詰まる， so my question is then two fold. Why does 詰まらない have the meaning it does (Does it just mean it's *not* packed, in the sense that it's boring?) and also, are there other 形容詞 that simply pulled themselves from the 否定形？
Lastly, did I phrase my question correctly? I know it's not directly related, but I felt a little weird writing とは, I never know how to reference words.

Comment: The `とは` in your question is fine.  The `作りました` is what I question.  I don't know that if it's wrong or not, but I'd say something more like `詰まらないとは「詰まる」から派生していますか？`

Comment: Why is it not 派生しました？Why would I use the gerund?

Comment: Because the situation/state after the 派生 occured has continued to the present.

Comment: @TokyoNagoya:  I understand that explanation (and because the dictionary had it that way), but I initially wanted to use `派生された`.  Why wouldn't that form work?

Comment: let me also point out an analogous case for 済みません (すみません)

Comment: @Cako It's not entirely analogous, though.  I don't think people generally say 詰まりません with the same meaning as つまらない.  But people **do** say すみません, すまない, すまん, and so on.

Comment: I the difference, I feel, is while these phrase *are* derived from verbs, 詰まらない is listed as 形容詞, and not until very recently was I informed it was 否定形. Isn't this a bit different, and somewhat strange?

Answer (score 2):

1. According to [this page](http://gogen-allguide.com/tu/tsumaranai.html) つまらない comes from the verb つまる(詰まる) + negative ない. 
   つまる originally means 動けなくなる(be stuck), 行動や思考が行き詰まる(come to a dead end) and started to mean 納得する(be convinced), 決着する(settle) as well. Over the years つまらない came to mean 納得できない (not convincing/satisfying?) and has changed its meaning to boring, uninteresting.
2. How about... くだらない、はしたない、たまらない、あっけない、さりげない、やりきれない、ふがいない、みっともない、もったいない... for more, see [73p](http://ir.library.osaka-u.ac.jp/dspace/bitstream/11094/4002/1/KJ00004305171.pdf)
3. I would say

> 「つまらない」は「詰まる」から来ているんですか？